# How do I prevent Lotus Notes users from forwarding or copying a message sent via Notes.jar API in Java?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I want to sent a programmatic mail using Lotus notes Notes.jar API in java. I need to enable Prevent copying option in my Java program. Is there any way to do this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See following [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=475&uid=swg21164209) regarding usage of $KeepPrivate field.
You will need to use this field when sending your email

Comment: totally agree... Just one note: A smarticon with the formula "FIELD $KeepPrivate := @DeleteField" (that every user can create) disables this "security" - feature

Comment: ya its correct. I used $Keep Private value in my code. Its working. `doc.appendItemValue("$keepprivate", 1);` Thanks.

Comment: For lotus notes 8.5 `doc.appendItemValue("$KeepPrivate", "1");` . Both will work in 8.0.1

Comment: Just reminder: you better use replaceItemValue, appendItemValue behaves badly if field exists already.